# Construct Array from Slices in Go

Tags: go

Given the following:

```
var positionTitles []string
var positionRelationships []string
var positionInstitutions []string

positionTitles = ["Director" "Provost" "Assistant Provost"]
positionRelationships = ["Tenured Professor" "Lecturer" "Adjunct Professor"]
positionInstitutions = ["UCSC" "UCB" "USC"]
```

How would I construct an array that looks like such:

```
Positions :=
 [{
   PositionTitle: "Director",
   PositionRelationships: "Tenured Professor",
   PositionInstitution: "UCSC",
  },
  {
   PositionTitle: "Provost",
   PositionRelationships: "Lecturer",
   PositionInstitution: "UCB",
  },
  {
   PositionTitle: "Assistant Provost",
   PositionRelationships: "Adjunct Professor",
   PositionInstitution: "USC",
  }]
```

The goal is to iterate over the Positions.

Go Playground I've started:
http://play.golang.org/p/za_9U7eHHT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a type that would hold all the pieces and iterate over the slices such that

```
type Position struct {
    Title, Relationship, Institution string
}

positions := make([]Position, len(positionTitles))
for i, title := range positionTitles {
    positions[i] = Position{
        Title:        title,
        Relationship: positionRelationships[i],
        Institution:  positionInstitutions[i],
    }
}
```

However, if you need it only to iterate, you don't need to create a type. See body of the `for`.

https://play.golang.org/p/1P604WWRGd

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Position struct containing the informations you need :

```
type Position struct {
PositionTitle         string
PositionRelationships string
PositionInstitution   string
}
```

and create an array (or slice) of those structs to iterate over them. Here is a working example : http://play.golang.org/p/s02zfeNJ63